# Clipboard manager for Mac that doesn't use any cloud service

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, copy-paste

I'm looking for a clipboard manager app/tool for Mac (Mavericks) that does not use any cloud service for saving/syncing data.

I mean that it doesn't save my content on any cloud server, but on my machine locally only.

Is there any?

Comment: you mean it should use iCloud ?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't save my content on any cloud server, but on my machine locally only

Comment: Do you want it to sync on other devices, or just manage the Clipboard locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [Copyclip](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/copyclip-clipboard-history/id595191960?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo=4). It remembers a certain amount of clips. You can also blacklist apps from which it should not clip something, for instance password managers.
It does not use any kind of cloud. It is only local.

To verify that it does not use any cloud services. You can block the app from accessing the internet. OS X Firewall or third party app. Or you can check all established internet connections with:

```
lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"
```

Or trust the developers that they have not put any hidden cloud abilities into the app. Or use some OpenSource app and check the code. Or develop yourself.

Comment: it doesn't use 3rd party cloud service?

Comment: answer edited: no cloud service at all

Comment: answer edited: 2 ways

Comment: 2 more ways. check answer

Answer (score 3):

I use [flycut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut), an open source fork of jumpcut, available in the [app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987).

Comment: it doesn't use 3rd party cloud service?

Comment: No, everything stored locally.

Comment: @Elad Benda - There's an option in the General settings for "Dropbox sync" which is OFF by default. Change the "Clippings" setting to "After each clip" and copy something. You will see the file `~/Library/Application Support/Flycut/com.generalarcade.flycut.plist` has been updated and contains your clipboard contents.

Answer (score 0):

[Clipy](https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy) is open source and does not use any cloud service - just stores the clipboard history and also allows to have a list of pre-defined snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The following python script will save text on the clipboard to a file on the desktop, with a datestamp.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# getTextclip v.1.3 : Get Text from Clipboard.
# This script saves a text file with any text data found on the Mac Clipboard.
# If Clipboard.txt exists, the text is appended, with a datestamp.

from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSPasteboardTypeString, NSPasteboardTypeRTF, NSPasteboardTypeString
import os, syslog
import datetime

# Change this to whatever filepath you want:
outfile=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Clipboard.txt")

now = datetime.datetime.now()

myFavoriteTypes = [NSPasteboardTypeString, NSPasteboardTypeRTF, NSPasteboardTypeString]
pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
best_type = pb.availableTypeFromArray_(myFavoriteTypes)
if best_type:
    clipData = pb.dataForType_(best_type)
    if clipData:
        clipString = str(clipData)
        clipFile = open(outfile, "a+")
        print ("Text added to Clipboard file.")

        clipFile.write(str(now)+'\n')
        clipFile.write(clipString+'\n')
        clipFile.write('\n')
        clipFile.close()
else:
    print ("No clipboard data was retrieved.")
    print ("These types were available:")
    print (pb.types())
```

Apple's Script Editor app has an option in its Preferences to show a Script menu in the menubar. You can then save this script to /Library/Scripts (or subfolder) and you can then run it from the menu.